# Integral for multiple indicator functions over a space

Tags: probability, integration

I have this bunch of integrals I'm trying to solve.
$$\int_{X^4}f_{12}f_{13}f_{14}f_{23}f_{24}f_{34}\;dx_1dx_2dx_3dx_4$$
where $f_{ij}=\mathbb{1}(\|x_i-x_j\|\leq r)\|x_i-x_j\|^a$ for $i,j=1,2,3,4$, and $X\subset\mathbb{R}^d$, $a\in\mathbb{R}^d$.

I know that solving $\int_X\mathbb{1}(\|x-y\|\leq r)\|x-y\|^a\,dx$ using spherical coordinates gives $$\int_{B^d(0,r)}1(\|z\|\leq r)\|z\|^{a}\ dz=\frac{d\kappa_d}{a+d}r^{a+d}, \mbox{ where $\kappa_d$ is the volume of the $d$-dimensional unit ball.}$$
I have tried to regroup the first integral thus:
$$\int_{X}\bigg[\int_Xf_{12}f_{14}dx_1\int_Xf_{23}f_{24}dx_2\int_Xf_{13}f_{34}\;dx_3\bigg]dx_4.$$
Does anyone have a clue to solving
$$\int_Xf_{12}f_{14}dx_1=\int_X\mathbb{1}(\|x_1-x_2\|\leq r)\mathbb{1}(\|x_1-x_4\|\leq r)\|x_1-x_2\|^a\|x_1-x_4\|^adx_1?$$